# how to improve the execution time of this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a dimension which has around 11.000.000 records, 4 tables are joined to each other in ETL process to fill my dimension(dimtst).

```
insert into dimtst
select .... from  tdpst left outer join fhist 
left outer join dp2act
left outer join dp2cust
```

above query lasts alot(`tdpst` has 11 records and above query lasts around 15 minutes), Hence I created a temp table which joined
`tdpst` and `fhist` and stored the result in `tmpDpsInf`(another temporary table which I created).

### then `tmpDpsInf`  will join with `C` and `D` in another query which has adequate execution time.

```
create table TMPFHIST
(
  abrnchcod NUMBER(4) not null,
  tbdptype  NUMBER(3) not null,
  cfcifno   NUMBER(8) not null,
  tdserial  NUMBER(3) not null,
  aistate   NUMBER(1)
)

--------------
create table TMPDPSINF
(
  abrnchcod     NUMBER(4) not null,
  tbdptype      NUMBER(3) not null,
  cfcifno       NUMBER(8) not null,
  tdserial      NUMBER(3) not null,
  ausrcode      NUMBER(4) not null,
  tdtitle       VARCHAR2(82),
  tdopndat      DATE,
  tdrnwdat      DATE,
  tdclsdat      DATE,
  acurrcode     CHAR(3) not null,
  abu_abrnchcod NUMBER(4) not null,
  aistate       NUMBER(1)
)
create table tdpst  
(
  abrnchcod     NUMBER(4) not null,
  tbdptype      NUMBER(3) not null,
  cfcifno       NUMBER(8) not null,
  tdserial      NUMBER(3) not null,
  ausrcode      NUMBER(4) not null,
  tdtitle       VARCHAR2(82),
  tdopndat      DATE,
  tdrnwdat      DATE,
  tdclsdat      DATE,
  acurrcode     CHAR(3) not null,
  abu_abrnchcod NUMBER(4) not null
)
--------

tmpDpsInf fills with below query:
    insert into tmpDpsInf
      select /*+parallel(12)*/
       d.ABRNCHCOD,
       d.TBDPTYPE,
       d.CFCIFNO,
       d.TDSERIAL,
       d.AUSRCODE AUSRCODE,
       d.tdtitle,
       trunc(d.tdopndat) TDOPNDAT,
       nvl(d.tdrnwdat, d.tdopndat),
       nvl(d.tdclsdat, to_date('1500/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')) tdclsdat,
       d.acurrcode acurrcode,
       d.ABU_ABRNCHCOD ABU_ABRNCHCOD,
       tmp.aistate
        from tdpst  d
        left outer join fhist tmp
          on d.ABRNCHCOD = tmp.ABRNCHCOD
         and d.TBDPTYPE =  tmp.TBDPTYPE
         and d.CFCIFNO =   tmp.CFCIFNO
         and d.TDSERIAL =  tmp.TDSERIAL
       where d.TDOPNDAT <= currdate
```

---

1   Plan hash value: 3720425100
2
3   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4   | Id  | Operation                        | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
5   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |          |    12M|  1994M|  4248   (3)| 00:01:17 |        |      |            |
7   |   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                  |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
8   |   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)            | :TQ10002 |    12M|  1994M|  4248   (3)| 00:01:17 |  Q1,02 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
9   |*  3 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER BUFFERED|          |    12M|  1994M|  4248   (3)| 00:01:17 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
10  |   4 |     PX RECEIVE                   |          |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
11  |   5 |      PX SEND HASH                | :TQ10000 |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |
12  |   6 |       PX BLOCK ITERATOR          |          |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
13  |   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TMPFHIST |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
14  |   8 |     PX RECEIVE                   |          |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
15  |   9 |      PX SEND HASH                | :TQ10001 |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
16  |  10 |       PX BLOCK ITERATOR          |          |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
17  |* 11 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TDPST    |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
18  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19
20  Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
21  ---------------------------------------------------
22
23     3 - access("D"."TDSERIAL"="TMP"."TDSERIAL"(+) AND "D"."CFCIFNO"="TMP"."CFCIFNO"(+) AND 
24                "D"."TBDPTYPE"="TMP"."TBDPTYPE"(+) AND "D"."ABRNCHCOD"="TMP"."ABRNCHCOD"(+))
25    11 - filter("D"."TDOPNDAT"<=TO_DATE('20130601','yyyy/mm/dd'))
26
27  Note
28  -----
29     - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=4)
30     - Degree of Parallelism is 10 because of hint

---

I executed above query with /*+leading (d,tmp)*/ hint.the plan is shown below:

---

Plan hash value: 1033900074

---

### | Id  | Operation                  | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |          |    12M|  1994M|  4255   (3)| 00:01:17 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR            |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)      | :TQ10002 |    12M|  1994M|  4255   (3)| 00:01:17 |  Q1,02 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN OUTER BUFFERED|          |    12M|  1994M|  4255   (3)| 00:01:17 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE             |          |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH          | :TQ10000 |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|   6 |       PX BLOCK ITERATOR    |          |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TDPST    |    12M|  1774M|  4059   (2)| 00:01:14 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |     PX RECEIVE             |          |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |      PX SEND HASH          | :TQ10001 |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  10 |       PX BLOCK ITERATOR    |          |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |

### |  11 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TMPFHIST |  3730K|    67M|   178   (3)| 00:00:04 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |

### Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

3 - access("D"."TDSERIAL"="TMP"."TDSERIAL"(+) AND "D"."CFCIFNO"="TMP"."CFCIFNO"(+) AND 
              "D"."TBDPTYPE"="TMP"."TBDPTYPE"(+) AND "D"."ABRNCHCOD"="TMP"."ABRNCHCOD"(+))
   7 - filter("D"."TDOPNDAT"<=TO_DATE('20130601','yyyy/mm/dd'))

### Note

- dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=4)
- Degree of Parallelism is 10 because of hint

---

I created one index on `d.TDOPNDAT` and one index on (tmp.ABRNCHCOD, tmp.TBDPTYPE, tmp.CFCIFNO,tmp.TDSERIAL)

.In addition to,Optimizer didn't use any index, I force optimizer to use created indexes,but query cost increases Exponentially!!
after doing all of mentioned works, query time is still high!

dos any one have any suggestion to reduce this query time ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Creating the intermediate table shouldn't be necessary, as, given the correct information, the  query optimiser should be able to make a correct decision on the fastest way to do this in one step without requiring you to work out the intermediate step. Likewise with indexes, generally the query optimiser will get the decision right on whether or not to use them - as long as it has the right inputs (in the form of stats / constraints etc).

Indexes are not always good - they're powerful where a small subset of the data in the table needs to be found, but in cases where you're reading the whole table they won't help you much.

As a starting point, ask Oracle what plan it is using the execute your long running query. This can be done with:

```
explain plan for 
select .... from  tdpst left outer join fhist 
left outer join dp2act
left outer join dp2cust;
```

Then,

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

NOTE - I don't have a database on this laptop (it is the weekend), so there may be some typos in the commands above, see the docs if they don't work as expected.

Look at the results and consider:
    How is it joining the tables - is it using a hash, a merge join or nested loops? 
    Is it joining the table in the right order.

My guess here is that it will be making an incorrect decision on the join order or join type. Working on that assumption, the next thing I would check would be the cardinality estimates. Run the query again with a /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ hint (you'll need to actually run it with this hint in - not just explain plan it again) and check the difference between the estimated and actual row numbers using:

SELECT *
FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(FORMAT=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));

Check for big differences between the estimated rows and actual rows. A big difference mean a problem in the statistics that is leading the optimizer astray. From this point you can consider.

- Gathering aditional stats on the tables, for example if one of the tables has a skewed column that is in the join (see DBMS_STATS)
- Gathering extended stats if you are joining on two or more correlated columns

Then repeat and see if you get a performance improvement

Good luck..

Comment: Excellent advice.  I would add that if the OP is using parallelism for the temporary tables then she might want to also use it for the single-SQL method.  And also add it to the `INSERT` statement, not just the `SELECT` part.

Comment: we used the parallelism 16 for both of select and insert in our operational environment,it improved in comparison to our test environment but query time is still too high!

Comment: First of all ,thanks for quick answers :) please let us consider suggestions one by one and add some comments to some sentences:
1.As I know Oracle stores table data which are used by the query. Due to limited capacity of oracle cache, We have to manage our data volume for better execution time  and better performance. Hence, in addition to checking order joins ,we have to care of  data volumes which are used in query . temp tables are  good candidates for solving this issue.

Comment: 2.I used  ‘left outer join’ with where clause, hence oracle should not have full access to  table ‘tdpst’   ,It should consider where clause and delete rows  from  tdpst table which don’t  met the condition ,then it should do left outer join with remained data of tdpst and tmpfhist. Thus index on the field opndat would be useful in this case.

Comment: 3.thanks for ‘checking  join order’ suggestion. it would better to put the big table in the left side and small table in the right side in left outer joins . 
Tmfhist table has around 3.5 million records and is smaller than tdpst which has around 11 million records. 
I added details of plans to my question in question part.

Comment: I have a problem with executing SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(FORMAT=>'ALLSTATS LAST')).I will update this post ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

First off, its typically best practice to let the engine handle index selection. If an index isnt being used, it's usually because criteria for the join doesn't allow the index to be utilised correctly. Thats why your execution costs increase.

Temp tables are a good alternative if you have minimal IO and your temp database on a SSD drive. Environment is a factor here. If your data selection is large, consider pagination.

Otherwise I would recommend an indexed view. Your columns will be specified with your join and allowing index to be pre-computed for optimal results. I think Oracle calls them materialized views. It should also force computation of the join if you index fields from each of the tables.

If my answer is wrong, feel free to correct me. Most of my experience is from MSSQL. My Oracle experience is a little limited

Comment: I think Paging is useful when you want to improve the performance of query which are used in reports or by applications .My case is a  temp table which I wanna use all of its data in next step of my ETL process, Would you please let me know If I can use paging in this case with more details?

Comment: If its in an ETL process, I wouldnt implement pagination. I would look at why the index isnt being used. The engine will know if it can use an index or not. Once that's corrected, you should see a major improvement. You could also look at moving this query into a view that you could index again if you want to do more filtering during your ETL process.